# No browsers detected when debugging remote device with Ionic DevApp

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-devapp

I installed the Android SDK and also Ionic Devapp and after running

```
ionic serve --devapp
```

I find in my cmd that all is well and that Devapp established a connection with my device W_K400. In Chrome, when I inspect remote devices, I see my device in there.

However, I cannot debug the app as it sas that no browsers were detected.

[image]

What is going on here?